# imshow() function not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a program in python with packages numpy,scipy and matplotlib.pyplot. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc
im=misc.imread("photosAfterAverage/exampleAfterAverage1.jpg")
plt.imshow(im, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

for some reason the image isn't showing up (checked if I got the image, in that part it's all fine- I can print the array.).

Comment: Did you try calling `plt.show()`?

Comment: Yea that's kind of embarssement. Thank you!

Comment: @tiago, please post this as an answer to clean the Unanswered group...

Comment: @Saullo  clearing the unanswered list should not be a reason to make a comment an answer... It should be common...  Decency? Sense? Just plain community participation?

Comment: @rubenvb please, don't be generalist in your judgement... my petition was for this post only, where we indeed had a clear answer posted as a comment

Comment: @Saullo you'd be surprised how many answers are posted in comments. And it's also not good if a difficult question is answered with a not-so-good answer that doesn't cover it, resulting in the question disappearing for people who would have written a very good answer.

Comment: @rubenvb I agree with this concern of the community and I am one who looks for an unanswered questions, but this specific case already had a good answer

Answer (score 77):

You need to call `plt.show()` to display the image. Or use `ipython --pylab` for an interactive shell that is `matplotlib` aware.

Comment: For anyone, like me, who calls plt.show() within ipython for the first time in his/her life, it's better to know that plt.show(block = False) allows you to stay in ipython command line when showing the image. I'm using a macbook.

Answer (score 7):

"Interactive mode may also be turned on via `matplotlib.pyplot.ion()`, and turned off via `matplotlib.pyplot.ioff()`" [cf. matplotlib user guide](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode).